# Enabling jquery on my images index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have code which pulls from my Images and includes each one in a div with a *unique* `id` and a *uniform* `class`

```
<% @albums.at(3)["photos"]["data"].each do |data| %>
    <div id="<%= data["id"] %>" class="myImages" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <%= image_tag data["images"].first["source"] %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here, my block is pulling from the Facebook Graph API, but essentially it gives me the url for the image_tag

And on the same index page I have this modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my controller, I have:

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js 
    end
end
```

Now, I want to replace the contents of a modal by clicking on one of these images, exactly like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zlen/nvzte69x/)

I've been using jquery like this:

**views/images/select.js.erb**

```
$(".myImages").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".modal-body").html($(this).html());
  });
});
```

**What I don't understand** is when I add this jquery code to `select.js.erb` the function does not work on my images index page. I'm left with a modal-body of "...", not being replaced with the image.

**However** when I add this to my **index.html.erb**

```
<script>
  //the same jquery code
</script>
```

it works exactly like I need it to.

I would like to have all my jquery in a different file. Am I missing something specific to rails that isn't allowing me to refactor (I think that's the correct word) my jquery like I explained?